# Why my singleton wont work?

Tags: javascript, singleton, ecmascript-5

I'm beginner on JS, trying to understand how singleton works, and after reading much about so many singleton pattern, I conclude that the following singleton pattern would work,

```js
var singletonIns = (function() {
  var instance;
  function init() {
    var _pvtVar = 123;
    var pubVar = 111;
    var logPvt = function() {
      console.log(_pvtVar);
    };
    
    return {
      pubVar : pubVar,
      logPvt : logPvt
    };
  }
  return {
    getInstance : function() {
      if (!instance) {
        instance = init();
      } else {
        return instance;
      }
    }
  };
})();
```

**It does't throw any error on runtime**.

However, when i run this code `var abc = singletonIns.getInstance()` it returns `undefined`, and we cannot access `abc.pubVar`, **why is that?**

Please explained like I'm five yo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first time you run that function it doesn't return anything ?

Comment: I can not replicate the error. It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!instance) {
    instance = init();
```

... and then what? then you don't return anything. Add `return instance;` after that and you'll be fine.

You return the instance when it's initiated, but if it's not you just assign it and not return.

Comment: Wow, brilliant hehehe forgot to do that

Answer (score 1):

```js
var singletonIns = (function() {
  var instance;
  function init() {
    var _pvtVar = 123;
    var pubVar = 111;
    var logPvt = function() {
      console.log(_pvtVar);
    };
    
    return {
      pubVar : pubVar,
      logPvt : logPvt
    };
  }
  return {
    getInstance : function() {
      if (typeof instance == 'undefined') {
        instance = init();
        return instance;
        console.log(instance);
      } else {
        return instance;
      }
    }
  };
})();

console.log(singletonIns.getInstance());
```

Comment: you have to check type of instance variable if undefined then call init() else same as it is.. due to this you were not able to get value.. you can access pubVar that value because it is local/private scope for that function so private variable you can't access outside of any function.. Read scope article for js